# Query Data from Registry using SQL

Tags: sql, registry, querying

Currently we have a new system being implemented at our company. This new system stores a lot of their data within the Registry on Server1. On Server2, within the same network, we have our SQL Server installed.

How would I query the data they have stored within the Registry on Server1 from Server2, keeping in mind that the data is stored within the following registry path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/ Software/ Wow6432Node/ CompanyName/ EIC/ Directory Services/ Root/ CustomerSite/ Production/ Users

I would prefer to query this through a SQL view if possible.

Thank you

Comment: You could probably use xp_cmdshell to run REG QUERY commands, and then do a bunch of string manipulation on the result set to get what you need. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028.aspx

Comment: Although just because you *can* do something with sql server doesn't mean you *should*

Comment: What would be your suggestion to query this, if not SQL Server?

Comment: Try using a powershell script to get this data out of the registry. Then you can import it to SQL Server and query as needed.